# Installing ruby with rvm and making ruby visible to bash

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby, rvm, curl

I installed rvm according to the instructions from the official website.
Then I installed two ruby versions
While rvm was visible to bash, ruby was not.

[image]

I was browsing the web for a solution and I found the following command:
[image]

After this, bash was able to see ruby.
I can't understand how did this happen.
From my perspective, the command was absolutely useless as I just installed the latest rvm version.

Comment: Did you restart your bash session after installing RVM?

Comment: Indeed, in the meantime I executed '~/.bashrc'. I assume that was the real cause. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

From your second screen shot you may noticed that rvm add RVM path to `/home/octavian/.bashrc` . So bash will know about it. try

```
grep -i rvm /home/octavian/.bashrc
```

Same for sh (`/home/octavian/.shrc`)